# OSGi bundle as external webservice client

Tags: osgi, jax-ws, cxf, apache-felix, dosgi

I need to call an external webservice from my bundle which is deployed in **apache felix** container ( *I can not use ServiceMix, fuse...*)
I added the bundle **cxf-dosgi** (which can be downloaded from [here](http://repository.apache.org/service/local/repositories/releases/content/org/apache/cxf/dosgi/cxf-dosgi-ri-singlebundle-distribution/1.4.0/cxf-dosgi-ri-singlebundle-distribution-1.4.0.jar)) and put the following lines in my pom.xml:

```
                    <Require-Bundle>cxf-dosgi-ri-singlebundle-distribution</Require-Bundle>
                     <Import-Package>
                        javax.jws,
                        javax.xml.bind,
                        javax.xml.bind.annotation,
                        javax.xml.namespace,
                        javax.xml.ws,
                        META-INF.cxf,
                        org.apache.cxf,
                        org.apache.cxf.binding,
                        org.apache.cxf.binding.soap,
                        org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.spring,
                        org.apache.cxf.bus,
                        org.apache.cxf.bus.resource,
                        org.apache.cxf.bus.spring,
                        org.apache.cxf.buslifecycle,
                        org.apache.cxf.catalog,
                        org.apache.cxf.configuration,
                        org.apache.cxf.configuration.spring,
                        org.apache.cxf.endpoint,
                        org.apache.cxf.headers,
                        org.apache.cxf.management,
                        org.apache.cxf.phase,
                        org.apache.cxf.resource,
                        org.apache.cxf.transport,
                        org.apache.cxf.transport.http,
                        org.apache.cxf.transport.http.policy,
                        org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty,
                        org.apache.cxf.transports.http,
                        org.apache.cxf.workqueue,
                        org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.builder.jaxb,
                        org.apache.cxf.wsdl,
                        org.apache.cxf.wsdl11,
                        org.apache.cxf.jaxws.*,
                        *
                    </Import-Package>
```

I use the jaxws way to establish the communication:

```
QName SERVICE_NAME = new QName("http://test.com/", "MockImplService");
Service service = Service.create(new URL(endpointAddress + "?wsdl"), SERVICE_NAME);         
mockService= service.getPort(IMock.class);
```

When I run the example I have the following exception:

```
 Caused by: javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder$ConfigurationError: Provider org.apache.axis2.jaxws.spi.Provider not found
        at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder$2.run(FactoryFinder.java:138)
        at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder.doPrivileged(FactoryFinder.java:282)
        at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:125)
        at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder.access$200(FactoryFinder.java:42)
        at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder$3.run(FactoryFinder.java:273)
        at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder.doPrivileged(FactoryFinder.java:282)
        at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:168)
        at javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider.provider(Provider.java:39)
        at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:36)
        at javax.xml.ws.Service.create(Service.java:116)
```

any idea please ?

Answer (score 0):

Apache DOSGi is designed for exposing services as webservices, not for calling other webservices. Though, it probably contains some api to call other webservices.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In this case, what should I do ? Is there a solution to call an external webService ?

Comment: There definitely are alternatives. As you may see from my answer "corrections", dosgi may contain some code that can be used to called other webservices.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the axis jaxws implementation is used. You probably have a axis2-jaxws-xxx.jar on your classpath. Try to remove it. The JRA jaxws will be used instead (which should be fine for axis and better for cxf).